# Bash: How to keep lines in a file that have fields that match lines in another file?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal, grep

I have two big files with a lot of text, and what I have to do is keep all lines in file A that have a field that matches a field in file B.

file A is something like:

```
Name (tab)  #  (tab)  #  (tab)  KEYFIELD  (tab)  Other fields
```

file B I managed to use cut and sed and other things to basically get it down to one field that is a list.

So The goal is to keep all lines in file A in the 4th field (it says KEYFIELD) if the field for that line matches one of the lines in file B. (Does NOT have to be an exact match, so if file B had Blah and file A said Blah_blah, it'd be ok)

I tried to do:

```
grep -f fileBcutdown fileA > outputfile
```

EDIT: Ok I give up. I just force killed it.

Is there a better way to do this? File A is 13.7MB and file B after cutting it down is 32.6MB for anyone that cares.

EDIT: This is an example line in file A:

```
chr21 33025905 33031813 ENST00000449339.1 0 - 33031813 33031813 0 3 1835,294,104, 0,4341,5804,
```

example line from file B cut down:

```
ENST00000111111
```

Comment: In your first sentence you say that the files are over 400 MB in size, yet in your last sentence, they are only ~50 MB. What's the contents of `outputfile` after the 45 minutes? Btw, the CPU won't be the bottleneck here, but slow/fast harddrives can make a big difference.

Comment: Ah I should've been clearer. File B before cutting it down was 400MB+. After I threw out all the stuff I didn't need it was 32.6MB. This is just a 7200rpm drive, and the outputfile is... empty when I do less outputfile. Crap. Edited the original post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk fileB.txt fileA.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
FNR==NR {
    array[$0]++
    next
}

{
    line = $4
    sub(/\.[0-9]+$/, "", line)
    if (line in array) {
        print
    }
}
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { array[$0]++; next } { line = $4; sub(/\.[0-9]+$/, "", line); if (line in array) print }' fileB.txt fileA.txt
```

`GNU awk` can also perform the pre-processing of `fileB.txt` that you described using `cut` and `sed`. If you would like me to build this into the above script, you will need to provide an example of what this line looks like.

---

**UPDATE using files `HumanGenCodeV12` and `GenBasicV12`:**

Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk HumanGenCodeV12 GenBasicV12 > output.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
FNR==NR {
    gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,"",$12)
    array[$12]++
    next
}

{
    line = $4
    sub(/\.[0-9]+$/, "", line)
    if (line in array) {
        print
    }
}
```

This successfully prints lines in `GenBasicV12` that can be found in `HumanGenCodeV12`. The output file (`output.txt`) contains 65340 lines. The script takes less than 10 seconds to complete.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. File B has already been processed into another file, so I won't need that. I'll give your script a try right now and see what happens.

Comment: Hmm, it did work... sort of. This gave me an output file of 2.1MB, whereas another script I found and wrote up gave me an output file of 11MB (!!!). I'm still trying to figure out the difference.

Comment: Hmm, so it turned out that this script stopped about 1/5 to 1/4 of the way through instead of going all the way. That's weird. EDIT: That was for the one-liner script. It seems like the other one returned... nothing. Huh.

Comment: @Joe: It sounds like you have a few inconsistencies with your data. The script and the one-liner above should output exactly the same results. Would you be able to send me either more example data or your complete files (preferably before any processing)? I would recommend something like [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or [mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/).

Comment: Hmm. So just for the hell of it instead of doing awk -f script.awk fileB.txt fileA.txt I put in awk -f script.awk fileA.txt fileB.txt... and this returned the exact same thing as the other script I found. That's weird. I guess I could send you the files if you still want it but file B will have to be cut down (it's 400MB otherwise sorry).

Comment: @Joe: `FileB.txt` (as you describe in your question) must be the first in the argument list for this script to work correctly. You may have mixed up the filenames accidently? Also, a 400 MB file would become approximately 100 MB if you use some sort of compression. And that's very send-able. Run: `tar cjf files.tar.bz2 *.txt`

Comment: No -- definitely don't have the filenames mixed up. The readme file will explain what each of the files are. Ok -- here are the files http://dl.dropbox.com/u/108419362/Documents.tar   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/108419362/FileA.tar.gz   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/108419362/README.txt Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Joe: Please see the update. I'm not sure what the problem was that you're having, but the updated script above works for me. Also, the filesize of `output.txt` is 11 MB. This should match your expected results. A general note, if you have to find/remove duplicate lines/fields, think arrays, not grep. They save you from having to create multiple temporary files and quite a lot of time. HTH.

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly! Same thing as what grep -f did, but much faster. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You're hitting the limit of using the basic shell tools. Assuming about 40 characters per line, File A has 400,000 lines in it and File B has about 1,200,000 lines in it. You're basically running grep for each line in File A and having grep plow through 1,200,000 lines with each execution. that's 480 ***BILLION*** lines you're parsing through. Unix tools are surprisingly quick, but even something fast done 480 billion times will add up.

You would be better off using a full programming scripting language like Perl or Python. You put all lines in *File B* in a hash. You take each line in File A, check to see if that fourth field matches something in the hash.

Reading in a few hundred thousand lines? Creating a 10,000,000 entry hash? Perl can parse both of those in a matter of minutes.

Something -- off the top of my head. You didn't give us much in the way of spects, so I didn't do any testing:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

# Create your index
open my $file_b, "<", "file_b.txt";
my %index;

while (my $line = <$file_b>) {
    chomp $line;
    $index{$line} = $line;    #Or however you do it...
}
close $file_b;


#
# Now check against file_a.txt
#

open my $file_a, "<", "file_a.txt";
while (my $line = <$file_a>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @fields = split /\s+/, $line;
    if (exists $index{$field[3]}) {
         say "Line: $line";
    }
}
close $file_a;
```

The hash means you only have to read through file_b once instead of 400,000 times. Start the program, go grab a cup of coffee from the office kitchen. (Yum! non-dairy creamer!) By the time you get back to your desk, it'll be done.

Comment: I haven't really done much with perl or python before so... yeah. I'll give your script a try, nevertheless. Thanks for the help! I edited the OP so I include what both files look like.

Comment: Wait. I just noticed this thing doesn't actually output anything. What would I have to add on to your script to have it output stuff from file A that passes through? Sorry, don't know perl at all.

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the OP's requirement that the match "does NOT have to be an exact match, so if file B had Blah and file A said Blah_blah, it'd be ok".

Comment: @joe The [say](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) statement is new to Perl. It's like a `print` statement that automatically prints a `\n` at the end.

Comment: @ruakh - I figured the "not exact" requirement was more due to the use of `grep` instead of the initial requirements. There's no real definition of _how close_ it has to be. The main point I was making is that `grep` is slow in this case because of the algorithm it require: Time increases as a product of the number of lines in both files. BASH shell is powerful, but does have its limits. There are times to break out a real scripting language and this is one.

Comment: Truth is that BASH now has associative arrays which are like Perl's hashes. In theory, you could do the same thing in BASH I did in Perl. However, I can't imagine how well a BASH script would run with a million plus hashes. David Korn (author of Korhshell, a shell from which BASH derived a lot of its syntax) tried to turn Kornshell into a full blown language in [dtksh](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2643), but its syntax simply was just to clumsy to use. By that time, Perl was taking over. (When Perl has cleaner syntax than your scripting language, you're in trouble).

Comment: @DavidW.: "I figured the 'not exact' requirement was more due to the use of `grep` instead of the initial requirements": Ah, you may be right. Hopefully the OP will clarify this.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion. When I said it does not have to be an exact match, I meant it didn't. So if fileB had a line called Blah, and one of File A's lines had Blah_blah, that line in File A would have to be included.

Comment: @Joe You have to give a better definition of _not exact matches_. How close does a match have to be? Are we talking about substrings or if 9 out of 10 letters match? Soundex matches? If A has "blah_blah" and B has "bl", would that be enough to match? If hashes won't work, you can use binary trees. What you want to avoid is grepping each line in B. Shell isn't going to cut it.

Comment: @DavidW substrings. Wow. Should've thought of that word in the first place. Ok -- I'll try to be as clear as I can -- technically your example would work because what B has is a substring of A. But EVERYTHING in that line from B has to be a substring of A, not portions. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`grep -f` seems to be very slow even for medium sized pattern files (< 1MB). I guess it tries every pattern for each line in the input stream.

A solution, which was faster for me, was to use a while loop. This assumes that `fileA` is reasonably small (it is the smaller one in your example), so iterating multiple times over the smaller file is preferable over iterating the larger file multiple times.

```
while read line; do
  grep -F "$line" fileA
done < fileBcutdown > outputfile
```

Note that this loop will output a line several times if it matches multiple patterns. To work around this limitation use `sort -u`, but this might be slower by quite a bit. You have to try.

```
while read line; do
  grep -F "$line" fileA
done < fileBcutdown | sort -u | outputfile
```

If you depend on the order of the lines, then I don't think you have any other option than using `grep -f`. But basically it boils down to trying m*n pattern matches.

Comment: Hmm… forget it. It's what I wrote in my last sentence, you need to run m*n matching operations. Maybe you're better off loading the patterns into memory all at once and then iterate over fileA and skip all remaining patterns when finding the first match (using a better language than shellscript)

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. FileB after cutting it down I did sort it using sort. Grep -f is still running and outputfile is STILL empty though. Ugh. I'll give your solution a try in a second.

Answer (score 1):

use the below command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}($4 in a)' <your filtered fileB with single field> fileA
```